# Postgres cluster: password authentication failed for user “postgres”

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, multiple-instances, change-password

In my Postgres server have created a cluster using the command pg_createcluster listening on port 5433. To set the password for the user postgres I followed the following steps:

1. Edit the file nano /etc/postgresql/9.3//pg_hba.conf

Changing the line

host all all 127.0.0.1/32 md5

By line

host all all 127.0.0.1/32 trust

2. Change the password using the following commands

sudo -u postgres psql -h localhost -p 5433

postgres = # \ password postgres

Enter new password:

Enter it again:

postgres = # \ q

3. Edit the file nano /etc/postgresql/9.3//pg_hba.conf

Changing the line

host all all 127.0.0.1/32 trust

By line

host all all 127.0.0.1/32 md5

Shows no errors but to connect both the console and from the pgadmin3 triggers an error: password authentication failed for user "postgres". With this same process in the instance by default (main) I can connect successfully.

I appreciate any help because I do not find much documentation to work with instances of Postgres.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

thanks for the reply. I've had in the pg_hba.conf with the configuration of your response:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     trust
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
```

Changing the password:

```
# nano /etc/postgresql/9.3/<instance_name>/pg_hba.conf
# /etc/init.d/postgresql restart
# su - postgres
$ psql -U postgres -p 5433 -h localhost
Password for user postgres:
```

The authentication server prompts me to enter psql. The following configuration is that it allows me to enter the psql without password:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     trust
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
```

Changing the password:

```
# nano /etc/postgresql/9.3/<instance_name>/pg_hba.conf
# /etc/init.d/postgresql restart
# su - postgres
$ psql -U postgres -p 5433 -h localhost
postgres=# \password postgres
Enter new password:
Enter it again:
postgres=# \q
$ exit
# nano /etc/postgresql/9.3/<instance_name>/pg_hba.conf
# /etc/init.d/postgresql restart
```

Changing settings and entering again to psql:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     md5
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5


# su - postgres
$ psql -U postgres -p 5433 -h localhost
Password for user postgres:
psql: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
```

Comment: Facing the same issue, found solution?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need reload configuration, so all your changes can be applied. Connection port might not be opened and besides that you haven't clearly shared config for `local` connections. This should work fine:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     trust
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
```